# Using CSS to center a container block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center this container block with the background image on my website. The problem is whenever I use margins, it appears different on the mobile version of the website compared to the desktop version. Here are pictures of what the container looks like on [desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5GbB.jpg), on [mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcQyu.png), and the [line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBMO2.png) that controls the container.

Comment: share code also for better understanding.

Comment: This is a classic: https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gEiDt?editors=0110 `height: whatever;  width: whatever; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: I did share the code. Did you click on the hyper link labeled "line of code"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a fixed width of 840px. This is wider than the mobile screen, thus the container will go offbounds.

Consider using a percentage for the width, media queries or css grids.

Answer (score 0):

You're using fixed width. Try using percentage.

Comment: So would I also use percentage with the margins for both versions to to be affected equally?

Comment: For desktop you would normally use 80% and for mobile 100%